# How to make a Rails wildcard route for /user/2/files/any/path/to/a/file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, routes

I'm building a Rails application which lets users have like a personal folder where they can upload files or make another folders.

How could I make a route that could be simmilar to

```
/user/:id/files/:any_path
```

and matches routes like this

```
/user/2/files/some_folder/a_file.doc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to match a custom route like this:

```
match '/user/:id/files/*any_path'
```

This route would match `/user/2/files/3` or `/user/2/files/long/path/to/3`, setting `params[:any_path]` to `"3"` or `"long/path/to/3"`.

Starting from Rails 3.1, wildcard routes will always match the optional format segment by default. For example if you have this route:

```
match '*pages' => 'pages#show'
```

By requesting `"/foo/bar.json"`, your params[:pages] will be equals to `"foo/bar"` with the request format of JSON. If you want the old 3.0.x behavior back, you could supply `:format => false` like this:

```
match '*pages' => 'pages#show', :format => false
```

If you want to make the format segment mandatory, so it cannot be omitted, you can supply `:format => true` like this:

```
match '*pages' => 'pages#show', :format => true
```

This info and more details you can find on [**Rails routing from the outside in**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)